# How to overcome the error when AOT-compilation 'Cannot determine the module for class'?

Tags: angularjs, angular, aot, angular2-aot

JIT-compilation is worked. But, I decided to compile application using the
AOT-compilation. And I get the following error:

```
Cannot determine the module for class ProfileComponent 
Cannot determine the module for class ProfileComponent 
Cannot determine the module for class ProfileRESTService
```

My application consists of single module. At the same time, it has a lot of components and services. These are described in a single `@NgModule`. Variable `MODULES` contains array components and services, there's no `@NgModule`, just a array classes, almost.

modules.ts

```
...
import {ProfileModule} from './profile/module';

export const MODULES = [
    ...
    ProfileModule
];
```

profile/module.ts

```
...
import {ProfileComponent} from "./component/Profile/index";
import {ProfileRoute} from "./route/ProfileRoute/index";
import {ProfileRESTService} from "./service/ProfileRESTService";

export const ProfileModule = [
    declarations: [
        ...
        ProfileComponent
    ],
    routes: [
        ...
        ProfileRoute
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
        ProfileRESTService
    ]
]
```

app.module.ts

```
import {App}   from './app.component';
import {routing} from "./app.routing";
import {MODULES} from "./module/modules";

let moduleDeclaration = {
    declarations: [
       App
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
    ]
    bootstrap: [App]
};

for (let module of MODULES) {
    if (!!module['declarations'] && module['declarations'] instanceof Array) {
        for (let item of module['declarations']) {
            moduleDeclaration.declarations.push(item)
        }
    }
    if('routes'){...}
    if('providers'){...}
    if('imports'){...}
}

@NgModule(moduleDeclaration)
export class AppModule {}
```

I suppose that when AOT compilation, analyzes the object that is passed in `@NgModule`, in my case, this object is not yet ready. It will be difficult to re-write the application describing each module as `@NgModule`. How can I solve the problem with the dynamic executable `moduleDeclaration`?

Comment: dynamic and ahead of time. I don't think that's going to be possible. What's the reason you put everything in one NgModule, and not just make several NgModules which is adviced

Comment: @PierreDuc, When starting out, we decided that all the components will be global. The application has grown and it would be difficult to describe the export and import for each module. I think that the best solution would be to write a script that will gather the description of the modules into a single object and pass the object in `@NgModule`

Comment: Maybe this issue is related to your problem - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13590